# unknown image format on axes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm working on CBIR, in my GUI I've 6 axes one for query image 5 for resulted images. For displaying images on axes my code is

```
function displayResults(filename,hObject, eventdata, handles)
% Open 'filename' file... for reading...
fid = fopen(filename);
for N=6:1:10
    imagename = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(imagename), break, end       % Meaning: End of File...
    x=imread(imagename);
    axes(handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N)));
    imshow(x)
    xlabel(imagename);  
end
fclose(fid);
```

and calling function is in pushbutton `function Texture_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)`. calling function is `displayResults('textureResults.txt',hObject, eventdata, handles);`

this is my output window before

```
![before pressing pushbutton](http://s1273.photobucket.com/user/Chethan_tv/media/fig5_zps64ca6452.jpg.html?sort=3&o=1)
```

after pressing pushbutton

```
![final output](http://s1273.photobucket.com/user/Chethan_tv/media/fig5_zps98c96f8f.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0)
```

What just happened to image quality?

Comment: Before using above code i was getting clear images, but that was not a GUI window, instead just a figure window. any thing wrong in called function?

Comment: I would be tempted to point the finger at the `imshow` function here - I don't think it's meant for use outside your normal "figure" environment. Another potential candidate looks like that call to `axes`. Perhaps you could try drawing it with `image(x, 'Parent', handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N)))` - does that help?

Comment: Well, slightly it is working even some images are not clear. .         `![output](http://s1273.photobucket.com/user/Chethan_tv/media/fig_zps761bcc6d.jpg.html)` also how did map values(x and y axis values) come from?

Comment: The link you provided gives file not found

Comment: `(http://s1273.photobucket.com/user/Chethan_tv/media/fig_zpsa48de802.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0)`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that that's **not** what the original images look like? There is nothing in the code you posted that should distort your data... or do anything to it, in fact, apart from display it.

Comment: yeah, in output side first image is clear and other 4 images should look like that. Don't know what had happened, Then which part of my code is wrong...! How to remove that map values?